# AS3 UILoader External Image Loop

Tags: xml, loops, actionscript-3, flash, uiloader

I am looping a code where n images are loaded in n UILoader components on the stage using a dynamic XML.

```
    var aLoader: UILoader = new UILoader();
MovieClip(parent).box1_mc.match1_mc.flag1_mc.source = "C:\\Saverio\\Scoreboard\\Flags\\Squared\\" + country01 + ".png";
aLoader.scaleContent = false;
addChild(aLoader);
```

However this loop keeps reloading the image, generating a blinking effect on the image that I don't want to show.

This basic function was running smooth when in AS2 I was using the loader.contentPath command.

I need to produce an AS3 project, and NOT an Air app.

Thank you

Comment: You are not even using the UILoader to load the image. You are directly setting the source of the image. Also, where is the loop?

Comment: Hi,
MovieClip(parent).box1_mc.match1_mc.flag1_mc is my UILoader istance.
The loop is made in the timeline which reloads this code.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this way:

```
var aLoader01: UILoader = new UILoader();
aLoader01.source = "C:\\Saverio\\Scoreboard\\Flags\\Squared\\" + MovieClip(root).country + ".png";
aLoader01.width = 330;
aLoader01.height = 220;
flag_mc.addChild(aLoader01);
```